# Hash Table Print "Stops Working"

Tags: c, hashtable

As practice (I'm a student), I'm implementing a basic `string` to `int` hash table in C. I have (I think) everything working, except the `print table function`. It starts to work, but Windows says *"hashtable.exe has stopped working"* after printing out three entries of one bucket, and I know the other ones are valid because I can retrieve their values at the command prompt thing I have. Here is my code, and any advice is valued:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

const char ESC_STRING[] = "zzzz";

struct a_container {
    char *string;
    int value; 
    struct a_container *next; 
};

typedef struct a_container Container;

struct c_list {
    Container **arr;
    int size;
    int bits;
}; 

typedef struct c_list Table;

void print_entry(Container *c) {
    printf("%s%s%d", c -> string, ", ", c -> value);
}

void print_table(Table *t) {
    Container *e;
    int i; 
    int length = t -> size;
    printf("%d\n", length);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        if(t -> arr[i] == NULL) printf("%s\n", "Null bucket.");
        for(e = t -> arr[i]; e != NULL && e -> string != NULL; e = e -> next) {
            print_entry(e);
        }
    }
}

Container *make_cont() {
    Container *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(Container));
    if(new == NULL) return NULL;

    new -> next = NULL;

    return new;
}

Container *make_entry(char *key, int value) {
    Container *n = make_cont();

    n -> string = key;
    n -> value = value;

    return n;
}

Table *make_table(int size) {
    Table *tab = NULL;
    int i; 
    int j = 2 << (size - 1);

    if(size < 1) return NULL;

    tab = malloc(sizeof(Table));
    tab -> arr = malloc(sizeof(Container) * j);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tab -> arr[i] = NULL;
    }

    tab -> size = j;
    tab -> bits = size;

    return tab;
}

void associate(Table *hashtable, char *key, int value) {
    int index = hash_index(hashtable, key, hashtable -> bits);
    Container *e = NULL;
    Container *n = NULL;

    if(hashtable -> arr[index] == NULL) {
        e = make_entry(key, value);
        hashtable -> arr[index] = e;
        return;
    }

    else {
        e = hashtable -> arr[index];
        n = make_entry(key, value);
        hashtable -> arr[index] = n;
        n -> next = e;
    }
}

int retrieve(Table *hashtable, char *look) {
    int index = hash_index(hashtable, look, hashtable -> bits);
    Container *e = NULL;

    //if(hashtable -> arr[index] == NULL) exit(1);

    e = hashtable -> arr[index];
    while(e != NULL && e -> string != NULL && strcmp(look, e -> string) > 0) {
        e = e -> next; 
    }

    if(e == NULL || e -> string == NULL || strcmp(look, e -> string) != 0) {
        exit(1);
    } else {
        return e -> value; 
    }
}

//djb2 algorithm by dan bernstein
//http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
unsigned long hash_code(char *key) {
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c; 

    while(c = *key++) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
    }

    return hash; 
}

int hash_index(Table *hashtable, char *query, int bits) {
    unsigned long hashCode = hash_code(query);
    unsigned int fold = 0; 
    unsigned int h; 
    int trim = 2 << (bits - 1);
    int mask = trim - 1;

    for(h = hashCode; h != 0; h >>= bits) {
        fold ^= h;
    }

    fold &= mask;
    return fold; 
}

int main() {
    char *i; 
    Table *hashtable = make_table(3);

    associate(hashtable, "Erica", 323);
    associate(hashtable, "Kitty", 18);
    associate(hashtable, "Dawg", 3);
    associate(hashtable, "Dahhhhhhg", 43);
    associate(hashtable, "Kat", 7);

    //print_table(hashtable);

    while(1) {
        printf("%s", "Look something up: ");
        scanf("%s", i);
        if(strcmp(i, ESC_STRING) == 0) break;
        printf("%d\n", retrieve(hashtable, i)); 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you `Container **arr` instead of `Container *arr`?

Comment: Please learn to debug -- using a debugger and/or diagnostic printfs. SO is no substitute for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the value of a variable until you assign it one. In `main`, you pass the value of `i` to `scanf`, but you haven't assigned it a value yet. So you are passing `scanf` a garbage address which causes the program to crash when `scanf` tries to store something at that nonsense location.

Comment: That's not what's crashing - it's the print_table. My silly little infinite loop query thing works fine.

Comment: @AdamR. When you have undefined behavior, other people can't tell how specifically it's failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough your program compiles and runs fine as-is on my system, even the `print_table()` function, the lookups... all runs fine for me. That said, you should fix the error Adam pointed out: storing the input string at an address that is undefined is a serious bug regardless.

Merely declaring `char *i;` will result in `i` containing an address equal to whatever was last on the execution stack at that location. In other words, it could be *anything*. Because of this, the program may actually work sometimes on some computers and other times not, depending on whether `i` happens to contain a valid address. That might explain why your program worked as-is on my computer but not on yours.

Instead you could write:

```
char i[128];
```

...and...

```
scanf("%s", i);
```

Comment: It works on my Linux partition under GCC. So should I just chalk this up to VS2013 being odd?

Comment: @AdamR. No, you should consider that you have non-portable code and undefined behavior, and track down the bug by using the debug functions of VS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's modified code that can explain what's wrong (from function `print_table`):

```
if ( t->arr[i] == NULL ) printf("%s\n", "Null bucket.");
// what happens when t->arr[i] == NULL ?
// e->string is a NULL pointer deference.
for ( e = t->arr[i]; e != NULL && e->string != NULL; e = e->next ) {
    print_entry(e);
}
```

Fix:

```
if ( t->arr[i] == NULL )
    printf("%s\n", "Null bucket.");    
else
    for ( e = t->arr[i]; e != NULL && e->string != NULL; e = e->next ) {
        print_entry(e);
    }
```